# Error handling in unix Script for subshell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, informatica

I have a wrapper.sh script which call another script run_workflow.sh which eventually calls a workflow. I would like to handle error for run_wrklow.sh...i.e, if the workflow is executed successfully then i need to call another script run_workflow2.sh which triggers another workflow.

Here is the sample code...Please suggest me how to handle errors

wrapper.sh

```
sh run_workflow.sh #trigger workflow1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Workflow Failed"
else
echo "Wrokflow Success"
sh run_workflow2.sh #trigger workflow2
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Workflow2 Failed"
   else
   echo "Workflow2 Success"
   fi
fi
```

However when i try this code I'm not able to return failed status.

Comment: Does `run_workflow.sh` exit with a non-zero return code when something fails?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion.  You don't need to explicitly test `$?`, the syntax is that `if` is followed by a command (`[` is the `test` command).

```
exit_value=1   # default failure

if sh run_workflow.sh #trigger workflow1
then
    echo "Wrokflow Success"

    if sh run_workflow2.sh #trigger workflow2
    then
        echo "Workflow2 Success"
        exit_value=0
    else
        echo "Workflow2 Failed" >&2
    fi
else
    echo "Workflow Failed" >&2
fi

exit $exit_value
```

Note that I echo error messages to `stderr` (`>&2`).  The `exit` command returns an error, which is an integer between 0-255.  By convention we return 0 on success and 1 on error.

I also indented my code, which all experienced programmers do.

Comment: More important: change `run_workflow.sh` so that it will `exit 1` after some failure.

Comment: @WalterA:  I assumed that was already the case since `$?` is tested in the wrapper.  Maybe that was optimistic.